# Get specific data from HTML using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to make a list of items in the Steam Marketplace. I have found the text that I need to extract from the HTML code, but I'm not sure how to write the code to get the small specific text that I need. For example, the "Nova | Koi (Factory New)" is what I need from here: http://gyazo.com/ed241fc3657308e43c836208407071ce

And I plan on running the code to get this text by going through "result_0_name" to "result_10_name". (There are 10 results per page) Then go through each page and run it again, and save it all in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Since you posted no code, there is nothing to check.
Try looking into something like this
PHP's HttpRequest
https://php.net/manual/en/httprequest.send.php